# onEdit trigger invokes permissions- how to overcome?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth

I've been making a few templates and part of their scripts involves the use of onEdit to timestamp cells and to also insert '0' when a particular cell meets a criteria.

The master sheet makes copies of these sheets as part of a script- I've realised the onEdit trigger would need adding manually which isn't practical as we would make about 10-15 sheets a day. Is it possible this can be done automatically upon creating the copy?

Whilst trying to find a solution, I've used this code and assigned to a button on one of the template:-

```
function addTrigger(){

  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit')
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}
```

Which works except on a new copy, you'd press this button but it then ask for permissions, once granted, you'd then have to press the button again to have the script run. Is there anyway I can streamline this process, perhaps grant permissions then add trigger in one click?

I've also read something about deploying my script as a Add on- would this work as I think it would- the user would only need to grant permissions one time and use the same script on multiple copies of the templates? The templates all have a script that basically send results to the last row of a certain tab within a spreadsheet depending on type of analysis that has been run as well as the onEdit script. There are some differences in the templates scripts, one of them also notifies a member of staff upon completion of the spreadsheet.

If anyone has ideas, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: I suppose you could capture the user email from the event object and use it with conditional logic to accomplish that.